# iOS app that creates HTML5 content

Tags: ios, html, ftp

I'm trying to do something a bit complicated and I'm not entirely sure how to go about it. Could you please give me some pointers on the tech I should use and how I should go about implementing this. Here's what I need to do:

- Create an iOS app that allows the user to upload pictures from his camera roll and modify variables with sliders. **(so far so good)**
- These variables and graphics are used to modify some htlm5 code (i.e. the graphics the user supplies are called by the hmtl code and the variables modify some set variables in the script) **(Do I just edit the code as a string?)**
- The code is put together and uploaded to a server where it is accessible at a unique URL. The user can save multiple times and each time it creates a new URL. **(Do I need an FTP here?)**

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too general, but as far as I can help, Yes you have to create and edit some html source texts, and append every object that user is adding to the page as some html codes, files, css, etc.

and for uploading, if you want the user to upload the site to his/her own ftp server or web hosting service, yes you need FTP connection to create with the server.

But if you want your user to upload the website to a space you're providing for the user, then you need some server part and maybe some APIs. then you may use FTP or even some APIs to create and update files on your server. It highly depends on the service you want to provide.